# Latexmk cannot find pdflatex in TeXworks

Tags: latexmk, texworks

I'm attempting to to get Latexmk working on a new computer running OSX Catalina. I've installed MacTeX and TeXworks. As far as I can tell, all of my settings are consistent with the settings on my old computer, where this worked fine. I can compile .tex documents fine (on the new computer) in TeXworks using the PDFLaTeX option. However, if I try and compile via Latexmk in TeXworks, it fails and I get the error:

> Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...

> sh: pdflatex: command not found

However, if I compile the .tex file using Latexmk via Terminal, there are no issues.

Weirdly, if I open TeXworks via Terminal (instead of from Applications), the Latexmk compile option in TeXworks compiles without any issues.

I would love to figure out why I am unable to compile using Latexmk.

**Other information that might be relevant:**

$ which pdflatex returns /usr/local/bin/pdflatex

$ which latexmk returns /Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk

Both of these paths are present in TeXworks Preferences > Typesetting > Paths for TeX and related programs.

$ echo $PATH returns
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

This is version 4.70b of Latexmk.

SOLVED: Added the paths in TeXworks Preferences > Typesetting > Paths in the TeXworks that was opened via Terminal. The TeXworks opened via Applications is now able to compile via latexmk.

See below comment by John Collins for another solution.

Comment: Could you somehow be having more than one TeXworks installation?

Comment: It's definitely not a problem with more than one TeXworks installation.  I can both reproduce the problem on my computer that has a single installation and work around it.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because the current version of TeXworks doesn't give a suitable value to the PATH environment variable to programs it invokes.  This may change in a future version.  In contrast, at the command line, PATH does have a suitable value, which the installation of MacTeX arranges to happen.

Possible solutions:

1. Use TeXShop instead of TeXworks.  In TeXShop, latexmk works and is supported.
2. Configure latexmk by having one of its latexmkrc files set PATH suitably. A very simple-minded solution is to add the following line to a latexmkrc file:

   ```
    $ENV{PATH} .= ':/Library/TeX/texbin';
   ```

Fancier solutions are possible.